# jQuery.get returns old data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a control page for my site that allows the admin to change various things about the site.
One section allows for the admin to change pages.
I use jQuery.get on the page selected to find the contents, then display that in a textarea.
This all works fine, and the admin can modify the content and save it.
The content IS saved, and the page DOES change once refreshed.
However, when I use jQuery.get again to find the new contents of the page, it comes back with the
original page content, the old data.
No matter how many times I refresh the page the textarea always shows data that shouldn't exist
anymore.
Here is the isolated edit page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#editpage').click(function() {

        var page = $('#page').val();

        $.get('pages/' + page + '.txt',{},function(data) {

            $('#display').val(data);

        });

    });

    $('#savepage').click(function() {

        var pageToChange = $('#page').val();
        var contents = $('#display').val();

        $.post('changepage.php',{page:pageToChange,text:contents},function(data) {

            $('#saveyay').html('<div class="success">Saved Changes</div>');

        });

    });

});

</script>
```

And changepage.php:

```
<?php

    if (array_key_exists('text',$_POST) AND array_key_exists('page',$_POST)) {

        file_put_contents('pages/'.$_POST['page'].'.txt', $_POST['text']);

    }

?>
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Fix your caching headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible reason for this is caching of the get request.

So try setting `cache: false` using [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) before the get request()

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```

Setting it using `ajaxSetup()` will set the cache property to false for every ajax request.

If you want to set the property for only one request then you can use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) with the custom options

Comment: Or on that particular request

Answer (score 0):

Your browser caching the results.

Switch from `get` to `ajax` and pass `cache: false` as one of your options.

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>  Type:
>   Boolean
>  If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
>   cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
>   correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
>   "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
>   other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
>   that has already been requested by a GET.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're html cache is being saved locally.

On the start of your javascript file place:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: But you can't tell all users to do that. A solution in the code is what is required.

Comment: Disabling the cache on the client-side is not the solution.

Comment: The answer has been updated - possibly copied from someone else's - since we made our comments.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question thinking he just got it while testing.

Comment: @Popnoodles I wrote that without even seeing other peoples answers and your comment, I didn't know someon else had already posted this. I got it from a google search. You shouldn't come to conclusions that fast.

Comment: Ok. But you *should* look to see if the answer had been posted. There's no need to post the same thing.

Comment: @Popnoodles I know, I should have looked.

Answer (score 0):

browser cache is problem try do some thing like add `?_= new Date().getTime()` to url